# Filling in plot with multiple curves

Tags: plotting, filling

How can I fill the area between the curves? I cant seem to fill all three of them...

[image: plot output - no code]

Comment: Please share code (instead of an image) and the definitions for your functions next time. It really helps in quickly trying out your examples and posting solutions.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want some kind of filling, you can just add from curve 1 to 3 as well:

```
Plot[{
  -x^2 + 2,
  -x,
  x
  },
 {x, -2, 2},
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}, 1 -> {3}}
]
```

[image: Plot with filling.]

The area above the yellow and green lines is darker because it's effective being filled twice. If you want the shading to be uniform, you can either use halirutan's answer, or you can specify a colour with no opacity as the filling:

```
Plot[{
  -x^2 + 2,
  -x,
  x
  },
 {x, -2, 2},
 Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, LightBlue}, 1 -> {{3}, LightBlue}}
]
```

[image: Plot with uniform filling.]

Answer (score 2):

How about creating the filling and the plot separately and combining them later?

```
yf[x_] := -x^2 + 2;
yg[x_] := -x;
yh[x_] := x;
plot = Plot[{yf[x], yg[x], yh[x]}, {x, -2, 2}];
fill = RegionPlot[yf[x] > y && (yg[x] < y || yh[x] < y), {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
  PlotPoints -> 50,
  MaxRecursion -> 3];
Show[fill, plot]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

```
yf[x_] := -x^2 + 2;
yg[x_] := -x;
yh[x_] := x;

Plot[{yf[x], yg[x], yh[x], Min[yg[x], yh[x]]}, {x, -2, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, None}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {4}}]
```

[image]

You can also use [`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html) as follows:

```
ParametricPlot[{{x, v Min[yg[x], yh[x]] + (1 - v) yf[x]}, {x, yg[x]}, {x, yh[x]}}, 
  {x, -2, 2}, {v, 0, 1}, 
 Axes -> False, Exclusions -> None, BaseStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]